# How to disable Resharper messages in VS 2019 statusbar?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I know it sounds weird, but this drives me crazy...

Resharper gives me an animated message in the VS status bar, zillion times a day (practically continuously). To make the thing worst, it is animated (slides from right into, the sides back to the right) This gets my eyes there, and interrupts my work, again practically repeats in every few seconds... The message is completely boring, btw:

> Sync solution: Roslyn projects changed but no projects saved

I do know how to hide VS Status bar completely, but this way I lose many useful information about Git, for example.

**Question**

Please recommend a way how to get the rid of either this particular message, or even all Resharper status bar messages.

[image]

Comment: The 3 outstanding updates notification is a distraction too ;)

Comment: at least that is not animating. The text sliding in and sliding out is really an amateur journeyman developer idea. Not just the moving object distraction, but sometimes *I literally have to hunt for the git icons on the status bar*, because Resharper eye candy idea also shifts those left and right zillion times a day.  Insane idea, especially from a productivity tool...

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you been noticing VS (devenv.exe) eating up more CPU? And possibly also seeing MSBuild.exe and ServiceHub.RoslynCodeAnalysisService32.exe eating up CPU at times as well?

Comment: @csrowell more, compared to what?

Comment: I suppose as compared to a Visual Studio without an open solution (or a solution freshly generated from a template). After upgrading to the 2020 ReSharper release, I noticed this behavior. It seems this is a symptom of a problem in Visual Studio itself. the IDE is repeatedly triggering "Design Time Builds" which causes this message to appear. A team at Microsoft is looking into it: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/961357/stuck-background-process-causing-sustained-cpu-thi.html

Comment: @csrowell, since I updated to RS2020.1.3 my system has come to a crawl.  I look in task manager and it is constantly building, sometimes several builds going on at the same time.  I often have to wait several seconds for key strokes to appear.  I disabled RS and everything is back to normal.  I'm doing a lot of Blazor lately - maybe that's causing it

Comment: @BradIrby, you may want to submit a ReSharper bug report via the Visual Studio menus: ReSharper... Help... Report a Bug or Submit Feedback...

My issue with Design Time Builds continues even with every VS extension disabled, so I know it's not caused by ReSharper.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  Its driving me round the twist.

Comment: not yet.........

Comment: I, too, am getting annoyed at hunting for the git button after doing a rebuild.

Answer (score 10):

Try to disable **ReSharper | Options | Environment | General |** "Read solution directly  from project/solution files."

Comment: Worked for me, too. My setup is VS2022 Preview 3 and ReSharper 2021.2 EXP 01 and a .net 5 solution created using dotnet CLI tool (if that matters).

Comment: Was having the same problem, this works but it still "flickers" when switching Git branches where there are major code/structural changes. Still, this is an improvement over the animating text. Hopefully ReSharper addresses this - animating stuff in a status bar where there are buttons the user can click is extremely poor UI/UX.

Answer (score 1):

There is the issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-487258. You could upvote it.

P.S. May be it's not 'a real answer', but it's definitely important link, and if  I post it as a comment for the question, it will be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Resharper|Options|Environment|PerformanceGuide and uncheck the option at top "Enable performance suggestions". That seems to be working for me, I was experiencing the same behavior.

Comment: done and has no effect The sliding text still slides in and out when I switch between files in the Solution Explorer

Answer (score 0):

If you can update, Visual Studio 16.6.0, released on May 19, 2020, appears to have fixed our issue that was causing ReSharper to constantly notify about Roslyn projects changing.

Comment: Updated to 16.6.2 nothing changed. Btw I do no care about Roslyn and Visual Studio supposed bug, for me it does not cause any performance degradation. I care about the insane idea, that a productivity tool (meaning. Resharper) a status message animates right to left half screen in and out, shifting/pushing UI buttons (source control buttons in the status bar). so I must see it zillon time a day, and hunt for the button like in a game, in case I want to click on it. This idea is insane in itself, and not allowing to disable it in an Option settings is simply ignorance.

Comment: Ah, I had hope your issue was similar to ours. Completely agree on the UI comments.